# RenderScript Error Combination Usage

Tags: java, android, renderscript

I'm trying to make a function that gets renderScript RGBA image and returns a matrix with a byte value.

The problem is that it returns me the following error, I searched for information but can not find anything about it and the only alternative I find is that the output is the same type and only save the results into one of the channels (eg Red).

**ERROR:**

```
10-15 16: 34: 35.006: E / AndroidRuntime (771): android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination usage.
```

**RenderScript Code:**

```
void rootTable(const uchar4 *v_in, uchar *v_out){
    *v_out = (int)rsGetElementAt_uchar(params, getIndexParams_Table(v_in->r>>3, v_in->g>>3, v_in->b>>3));
}
```

**Java Code:**

```
Allocation imageInAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(r, bmp, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

byte[] arrayParams = this.readParamByte(R.raw.params_table);
byte[] arrayColor = new byte[bmp.getWidth()*bmp.getHeight()];

Allocation params_table = Allocation.createSized(r, Element.I8(r), arrayParams.length);
Allocation dataOut = Allocation.createSized(r, Element.U8(r), bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()); 
params_table.copyFrom(arrayParams);
script.set_params(params_table);
script.forEach_rootTable(imageInAlloc, dataOut);

dataOut.copyTo(arrayColor);
```

The function is correct, so that the failure rate of entry and exit are distitnos but there is no way to do this?

Thank a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other stack trace information from the error you report above? Also, did you change the order of the words? I can't find "Invalid combination usage" anywhere in our codebase, but I do find "Invalid usage combination" (which unfortunately still doesn't make sense for what else you are seeing). There is at least one error that I spot immediately. Your "params" Allocation is of type I8, but you then are pulling from it as a uchar. That doesn't work, so you will need to call rsGetElementAt_int() instead, which lets you get rid of your int cast as well.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone has the same problem renderScript checks that the input and output is the same type, etc. To avoid this, you must modify the ScriptC_"filename".java, and look for the forEach_"function" function and remove the following:

```
// Verify dimensions
    Type tIn = ain.getType();
    Type tOut = aout.getType();
    if ((tIn.getCount() != tOut.getCount()) ||
        (tIn.getX() != tOut.getX()) ||
        (tIn.getY() != tOut.getY()) ||
        (tIn.getZ() != tOut.getZ()) ||
        (tIn.hasFaces() != tOut.hasFaces()) ||
        (tIn.hasMipmaps() != tOut.hasMipmaps())) {
        throw new RSRuntimeException("Dimension mismatch between input and output parameters!");
    }
```

Comment: Please don't do this, as it is guaranteed to break your code. The type checking here is to ensure that your program will actually operate correctly. I would really appreciate it if you would remove this answer, since it is completely misleading to other developers.